# Liquid template refer to first item in set?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid

I'm building a navbar menu with Jekyll, Liquid, and Bootstrap 3.

Right now I have a YAML list of urls that can be accessed through Liquid at a variable `site.sections` in my Jekyll `_config.yml` file. I'm trying to build the navbar with the following:

```
{% for section in site.sections %}
    <li><a href="{{ section.url }}">{{ section.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I also want to make it so that the first item in `site.sections` will show as active, that is, I want the first list item returned by the for-loop to be output as

`<li class="active"><a href="{{ section.url }}">{{ section.title }}</a></li>`

How do I construct the loop with Liquid so that I can output the first item as active and the rest as standard list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of trying to add the class in your liquid, you should utilize the selectors available in CSS to apply your new rules to that element. Assuming your wrapping `<ul>` has an id `sections`:

`#sections li:first-of-type {
  /* your rules here */
  color: 'red';
}`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize such selectors were available. Appreciated!

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. If you could accept the answer I'd appreciate it :)